# Reference request: vector space not naturally isomorphic to its dual

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I would like to recommend a book on (elementary) category theory to a friend.

I was looking specifically for one which would discuss (and, ideally, prove) that the identity functor on $\mathbf{Vec}_k$ is not naturally isomorphic to the dual functor $(-)^*$. Most of the books I know of just mention it at most.

The closest thing I have come across is Riehl's *Category theory in context*.

Mac Lane's book does define dinatural transformations, and uses them to show that Euclidean vector spaces are naturally isomorphic to their duals, but I couldn't find anything on finite dimensional vector spaces in general. I wouldn't be surprised if I had just missed it though.

The (very good) answers to this question on the site also don't mention any book.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but I am not absolutely certain) that in the book by Blyth (futher linear algebra) there is a prof (without even mentioning categories nor functors!). But I dont have my copy of the book with me at home.